# Receiving a client variable from another server using socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io, irc

### Overview

I'm working with two entities: (i) an IRC webapp and (ii) an IRC bot. There is a bot variable `botVariable` that I'm interested in passing over to the IRC webapp client. I've tried to use `socket.io` to do this and failed. **To me, what makes this problem interesting is that I'm trying to pass a value not from the IRC webapp server to the webapp client, but from the bot server to the webapp client.**  This is the first time I've used socket.io. Both the bot and the irc webapp are hosted on (different) heroku urls.

### Bot code (server-side)

For the bot, I have the following code:

```
var botVariable = "bot string"; //botVariable is global.

var io = require('socket.io')(HTTPS);
io.on('connection', function(botVariable) {
    //When client connects for the first time, send him the value immediately
    socket.emit('new_value', botVariable);
    console.log(botVariable);
});

console.log("End of bot file.");
```

### IRC code (client-side)

For the IRC-client code, I have the following:

```
<head>
<script src="https://bot.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>

<h2 id="bv" align="center"></h2> // where I eventually want to show botVariable

<script>
var socket = io.connect("http://bot.herokuapp.com/"); //this is where I host the bot

socket.on('new_value', function(botVariable) {
console.log(botVariable);
cBotVariable = botVariable; //I'm trying to make cBotVariable a global variable I can refer to on the client side
});

document.getElementById("bv").innerHTML = cBotVariable;
</script>
```

### Result/Error

When I load the site, `botVariable` fails to show up.  I receive the following error in my console.

```
> GET http://bot.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js 
(index):78 

> Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

When I go to bot.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js, it says `Could not find path: /socket.io/socket.io.js`.

I was under the impression that you didn't literally need to supply this file, but that the server somehow creates it on the fly.  I guess this is not the case?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing socket.io

```
npm install socket.io
```

and including it from:

```
<script src="PATH_TO_NODE_MODULES/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
```

or use CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.1.js"></script>
```